# Solution for selecting an appropriate category for something based off of the words within its description (java)

Tags: java, match, categories, cpu-word

Im trying to better organise the types of tasks regularly sent to my team based off of the titles and short comment people enter.

Our team only handles a handful of issues (maybe 10 or so) different types of tasks, so I've put together a list of common words used within the description of a particular type of task and i've been using this to categorise the issues. for example.... an issue might come through like "User x doesn't have access to office after hours, please update their swipecard access level". what i've got so far is if the comments contain 'swipecard' or 'access', its a building access type request.

I've quickly found myself with code that's LOTS of ... if contains, and if !contains...

Is there a neater way of doing what im after?

Comment: I think you should post actual code but as you do not have a problem which should be fixed, this question (including source code) should probably be asked at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it complex, it sounds like you have a [classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification) problem.

If you want to keep it simple, you're probably on the right track with your `if` statements and `contains()`.  To get to a cleaner solution, I would approach it as follows:

1. Create a class to modify your categories - give it two attributes: `String categoryName, List<String> commonlyUsedWords;`
2. Populate a list with instances of that class - one per type.
3. For each issue, loop through the list of categories and check how many words match, and store that as a percentage (e.g. 8 out of 10 words match, therefore 80% match).
4. Return the category with the highest match rate.